# ffmpeg gd support disabled

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg, gd

I have installed ffmpeg, imagic, and ffmpeg-php. It works, but I have a problem: GD support is disabled.

Here are my `phpinfo()` rows:

```
ffmpeg

ffmpeg-php version   0.7.0
ffmpeg-php built on  Oct 29 2012 14:22:26
ffmpeg-php gd support   disabled
ffmpeg libavcodec version   Lavc54.59.100
ffmpeg libavcodec license   nonfree and unredistributable
ffmpeg libavformat version  Lavf54.29.104
ffmpeg libavformat license  nonfree and unredistributable
ffmpeg swscaler version SwS2.1.101
ffmpeg swscaler license nonfree and unredistributable
ffmpeg codec_list   a64multi(v), a64multi5(v), aasc(v), amv(v), amv(v), anm(v), ansi(v), asv1(v), asv1(v), asv2(v), asv2(v), aura(v), aura2(v), avrp(v), avrp(v), avrn(v), avs(v), avui(v), avui(v), ayuv(v), ayuv(v), bethsoftvid(v), bfi(v), binkvideo(v), bmp(v), bmp(v), bmv_video(v), c93(v), cavs(v), cdgraphics(v), cdxl(v), cinepak(v), cljr(v), cljr(v), cllc(v), cpia(v), camstudio(v), cyuv(v), dfa(v), dirac(v), dnxhd(v), dnxhd(v), dpx(v), dpx(v), dsicinvideo(v), dvvideo(v), dvvideo(v), dxa(v), dxtory(v), eacmv(v), eamad(v), eatgq(v), eatgv(v), eatqi(v), 8bps(v), 8svx_exp(a), 8svx_fib(a), escape124(v), escape130(v), exr(v), ffv1(v), ffv1(v), ffvhuff(v), ffvhuff(v), flashsv(v), flashsv(v), flashsv2(v), flashsv2(v), flic(v), flv(v), flv(v), 4xm(v), fraps(v), frwu(v), gif(v), gif(v), h261(v), h261(v), h263(v), h263(v), h263i(v), h263p(v), h263p(v), h264(v), h264_vda(v), huffyuv(v), huffyuv(v), idcinvideo(v), iff_byterun1(v), iff_ilbm(v), indeo2(v), indeo3(v), indeo4(v), indeo5(v), interplayvideo(v), j2k(v), j2k(v), jpegls(v), jpegls(v), jv(v), kgv1(v), kmvc(v), lagarith(v), ljpeg(v), loco(v), mdec(v), mimic(v), mjpeg(v), mjpeg(v), mjpegb(v), mmvideo(v), motionpixels(v), mpegvideo_xvmc(v), mpeg1video(v), mpeg1video(v), mpeg2video(v), mpeg2video(v), mpeg4(v), mpeg4(v), mpegvideo(v), msa1(v), msmpeg4v1(v), msmpeg4v2(v), msmpeg4v2(v), msmpeg4(v), msmpeg4(v), msrle(v), mss1(v), mss2(v), msvideo1(v), msvideo1(v), mszh(v), mts2(v), mxpeg(v), nuv(v), paf_video(v), pam(v), pam(v), pbm(v), pbm(v), pcx(v), pcx(v), pgm(v), pgm(v), pgmyuv(v), pgmyuv(v), pictor(v), png(v), png(v), ppm(v), ppm(v), prores(v), prores(v), prores_anatoliy(v), prores_kostya(v), prores_lgpl(v), ptx(v), qdraw(v), qpeg(v), qtrle(v), qtrle(v), r10k(v), r10k(v), r210(v), r210(v), rawvideo(v), rawvideo(v), rl2(v), roqvideo(v), roqvideo(v), rpza(v), rv10(v), rv10(v), rv20(v), rv20(v), rv30(v), rv40(v), s302m(a), sanm(v), sgi(v), sgi(v), smackvid(v), smc(v), snow(v), snow(v), sp5x(v), sunrast(v), sunrast(v), svq1(v), svq1(v), svq3(v), targa(v), targa(v), theora(v), thp(v), tiertexseqvideo(v), tiff(v), tiff(v), tmv(v), truemotion1(v), truemotion2(v), camtasia(v), tscc2(v), txd(v), ultimotion(v), utvideo(v), utvideo(v), v210(v), v210(v), v210x(v), v308(v), v308(v), v408(v), v408(v), v410(v), v410(v), vb(v), vble(v), vc1(v), vc1image(v), vcr1(v), vmdvideo(v), vmnc(v), vp3(v), vp5(v), vp6(v), vp6a(v), vp6f(v), vp8(v), vqavideo(v), wmv1(v), wmv1(v), wmv2(v), wmv2(v), wmv3(v), wmv3image(v), wnv1(v), xan_wc3(v), xan_wc4(v), xbm(v), xbm(v), xl(v), xwd(v), xwd(v), y41p(v), y41p(v), yop(v), yuv4(v), yuv4(v), zerocodec(v), zlib(v), zlib(v), zmbv(v), zmbv(v), aac(a), aac(a), aac_latm(a), ac3(a), ac3(a), ac3_fixed(a), alac(a), alac(a), als(a), amrnb(a), amrwb(a), ape(a), atrac1(a), atrac3(a), binkaudio_dct(a), binkaudio_rdft(a), bmv_audio(a), cook(a), dca(a), dca(a), dsicinaudio(a), eac3(a), eac3(a), wavesynth(a), flac(a), flac(a), g723_1(a), g723_1(a), g729(a), gsm(a), gsm_ms(a), iac(a), imc(a), mace3(a), mace6(a), mlp(a), mp1(a), mp1float(a), mp2(a), mp2(a), mp2float(a), mp3(a), mp3float(a), mp3adu(a), mp3adufloat(a), mp3on4(a), mp3on4float(a), mpc7(a), mpc8(a), nellymoser(a), nellymoser(a), paf_audio(a), qcelp(a), qdm2(a), real_144(a), real_144(a), real_288(a), ralf(a), shorten(a), sipr(a), smackaud(a), sonic(a), sonic(a), sonicls(a), truehd(a), truespeech(a), tta(a), twinvq(a), vmdaudio(a), vorbis(a), vorbis(a), wavpack(a), wmalossless(a), wmapro(a), wmav1(a), wmav1(a), wmav2(a), wmav2(a), wmavoice(a), ws_snd1(a), pcm_alaw(a), pcm_alaw(a), pcm_bluray(a), pcm_dvd(a), pcm_f32be(a), pcm_f32be(a), pcm_f32le(a), pcm_f32le(a), pcm_f64be(a), pcm_f64be(a), pcm_f64le(a), pcm_f64le(a), pcm_lxf(a), pcm_mulaw(a), pcm_mulaw(a), pcm_s8(a), pcm_s8(a), pcm_s8_planar(a), pcm_s16be(a), pcm_s16be(a), pcm_s16le(a), pcm_s16le(a), pcm_s16le_planar(a), pcm_s24be(a), pcm_s24be(a), pcm_s24daud(a), pcm_s24daud(a), pcm_s24le(a), pcm_s24le(a), pcm_s32be(a), pcm_s32be(a), pcm_s32le(a), pcm_s32le(a), pcm_u8(a), pcm_u8(a), pcm_u16be(a), pcm_u16be(a), pcm_u16le(a), pcm_u16le(a), pcm_u24be(a), pcm_u24be(a), pcm_u24le(a), pcm_u24le(a), pcm_u32be(a), pcm_u32be(a), pcm_u32le(a), pcm_u32le(a), pcm_zork(a), interplay_dpcm(a), roq_dpcm(a), roq_dpcm(a), sol_dpcm(a), xan_dpcm(a), adpcm_4xm(a), adpcm_adx(a), adpcm_adx(a), adpcm_ct(a), adpcm_ea(a), adpcm_ea_maxis_xa(a), adpcm_ea_r1(a), adpcm_ea_r2(a), adpcm_ea_r3(a), adpcm_ea_xas(a), g722(a), g722(a), g726(a), g726(a), adpcm_ima_amv(a), adpcm_ima_apc(a), adpcm_ima_dk3(a), adpcm_ima_dk4(a), adpcm_ima_ea_eacs(a), adpcm_ima_ea_sead(a), adpcm_ima_iss(a), adpcm_ima_qt(a), adpcm_ima_qt(a), adpcm_ima_smjpeg(a), adpcm_ima_wav(a), adpcm_ima_wav(a), adpcm_ima_ws(a), adpcm_ms(a), adpcm_ms(a), adpcm_sbpro_2(a), adpcm_sbpro_3(a), adpcm_sbpro_4(a), adpcm_swf(a), adpcm_swf(a), adpcm_thp(a), adpcm_xa(a), adpcm_yamaha(a), adpcm_yamaha(a), vima(a), ass(s), ass(s), dvbsub(s), dvbsub(s), dvdsub(s), dvdsub(s), jacosub(s), microdvd(s), mov_text(s), mov_text(s), pgssub(s), realtext(s), sami(s), srt(s), srt(s), subrip(s), subrip(s), subviewer(s), webvtt(s), xsub(s), xsub(s), libfaac(a), libmp3lame(a), libx264(v), libx264rgb(v), libxvid(v), bintext(v), xbin(v), idf(v),
```

I use MAMP, PHP 5.3.6.
I have searched for solution for 3 days, no result sadly.

Comment: If GD support is disabled but you need it, the first thing I would do is to enable it. Have you tried that? http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=1836522

Comment: I have read that forum too. But in it I can't find the solution. It gives the advice to reinstall ffmpeg-php. I tried that with no result. I even tried to install it for different architetchtures, still no result. :( Does anyone have the same problem with MAMP, and does anyone solved it? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I'm no MAMP user. Check the requirements of ffmpeg-php for it's gd support. Write down these requirements. Check if your system provides all libraries that are required for that as well that the PHP sources have all other extensions required for that. If that is hard to you, just research the requirements, add them to the question with a description how you found out about the requirements.

Comment: I found the requirements here: http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/#requirements

There are the followings:
ffmpeg-0.4.9_pre1 or higher.
php-4.3.0 or higher
gd-2.0 or higher (the version of GD bundled with PHP works too)

And I have:

ffmpeg 1.0
php 5.3.6
gd bundled (2.0.34 compatible)

Comment: Ensure you enable the gd extension before you enable the ffmpeg extension in the php.ini.

Comment: In the same page I have read the followings in the FAQ: Q: I CAN'T GET IT TO INSTALL. WHAT'S THE DEAL?

Ffmpeg-php can sometimes be a pain to install. This is mostly due to the strange voodoo it has to do to detect if GD is available in PHP. Sometimes this fails for no apparent reason. Add to that the ever changing ffmpeg SVN and it can get even more tricky.

Comment: I coudn't find gd enabeling in php.ini. Maybe because in php 5.3.6 it is a built in modul.

Comment: No, even if the gd library is bundled with your PHP sources, it is not a built in module. It always needs to enabled. As long as your phpinfo() does not tell you that you have the gd library itself enabled, I would not worry at all that ffmpeg has no gd support.